# Entity Framework migration primary key error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I have simple db models:

```
public class Recipe
{   
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public String imageUrl { get; set; }
    public Nutrition nutrition { get; set; }
}

public class Nutrition
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double calories { get; set; }
    public double caloriesDailyNormPercentage { get; set; }
    public double protein { get; set; }
    public double proteinDailyNormPercentage { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to do the migration, I get an error:

> The entity type 'Nutrition' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'

I've tried every solution on the internet. I tried adding a `[Key]`, `[ForeignKey()]` - nothing is working.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost; Database=recepts; Username=postgres; Password=31029");

    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Nutrition> Nutritions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how does the migration looked like?

Comment: `Add-Migration FirstMigration` Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The entity type 'Nutrition' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: Is this all the code you have, no additional mapping configurations anywhere? From the looks of it, this should just work. Which EF version and which db provider are you using?

Comment: .NET 8 - Entity Framework 8 - Console App. Yes I know the code is very primitive and simple. It should work. That's the question, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: adding `[Key]` on `public int id { get; set; }` doesn't work? does the error still says the same thing? by convention, the `id` should be `Id` (notice the capital i) or `NutritionId`. alternatively you can set it with fluent API as shown by Amin's answer. so, its kinda weird that neither works. i do curious if the issue only happen on postgres ef driver.

Comment: I copied these two classes on new Console Project, with EF Core and PostgreSql packages installed. It works without modifying anything. Have you perhaps some Api fluent configuration added? Primary and Foreign keys created on the first table. Primary key on the second.

Comment: @nikar And which db provider?

Comment: `  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="8.0.0" />` Maybe I have the wrong dependencies?

Answer (score -1):

in defining a DbContext there are some important items:

a. if related table has primary key, you should use [Key] data annotation to inform compiler that this class is used for mapping table columns and for example if the database table has Id column as primary key , you should use [Key] the line before defining it

or override the OnModelCreating method in DbContext and adding [HasKey] to table mapping in the function:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
    .HasKey(p => new p.Id);
```

b. if related table has no primary key, you should override the OnModelCreating method in DbContext and adding [HasNoKey] to table mapping in the function:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    modelBuilder
    .Entity<MyEntity>(builder =>
    {
        builder.HasNoKey();
        builder.ToTable("MY_ENTITY");
    });
    }
```

I hope this help

Comment: You don't seem to be aware of EF's built-in conventions and they clearly don't intend to use keyless entity types.